# LO Error code on Samsung front loading washing machine

Tags: washing-machine, samsung

My washing machine is displaying the error code "LO" which means there is a locking issue. However I cannot seem to find any instructions on how to solve this issue and my machine won't work. The screen on the washing machine implies the sensor thinks the door is locked, but it isn't which may be relevant. The following site says replacing the locking mechanism "should" be easy, but no real instructions on what else can be done. Has anyone come across this issue with a solution?[image]

[https://www.thespruce.com/samsung-front-load-washer-fault-codes-2147297#:~:text=If%20the%20door%20fails%20to,switch%2C%20and%20tighten%20if%20needed](https://www.thespruce.com/samsung-front-load-washer-fault-codes-2147297#:%7E:text=If%20the%20door%20fails%20to,switch%2C%20and%20tighten%20if%20needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried unplugging it?

If the door fails to unlock after seven tries once the washer cycle is complete, you'll get the LO or FL code. Begin by unplugging the washer, and force open the door. Check the wiring connections to the door lock/switch, and tighten if needed.Apr 14, 2022
https://www.thespruce.com › samsu...
List of Samsung Front-Load Washer Error Codes - The Spruce